# PHP-PDO - Obtener ID en un select (funcion login)

Tags: php, pdo

Es mi primer tema acá y quería ver si me podían dar una manito...

Tengo un **login** que me funciona bien, hace la consulta a la tabla, busca el `user` y `pass` y si están ok, me redirecciona, lo hace perfecto, pero además necesito sacar un adicional de la tabla donde están los datos del **login**: el `id` de esa cuenta... ese `id` debe pasar a la página de redirección y mostrarse en un `input` oculto, es acá donde me pierdo, no me funciona recuperar el `id`.

### Este es el código que tengo:

*LOGIN.PHP*

```
session_start();

/*CONEXION A BASE DE DATOS MYSQL*/
$servidor="localhost";
$nombre_usuario="root";
$pass="ll";
$base_datos="baseDatos";
$mensaje="";

try
{
$conexion=new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor; dbname=$base_datos", 
$nombre_usuario,$pass);
$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

if (empty($_POST['rut_funcionario']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $mensaje="Debe ingresar rut y contraseña";
}
else{
    $consulta = "SELECT * from tbl_funcionario WHERE rut_funcionario = :rut_funcionario AND password = :password";
    $st = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
    $st->execute(
        array(
            'rut_funcionario' => $_POST['rut_funcionario'],
            'password' => $_POST['password']
            //'id_registro' => $_POST['id_registro']
        )
    );
    $contador = $st->rowCount();

        if ($contador > 0) {
            $_SESSION['rut_funcionario'] = $_POST['rut_funcionario'];
            $_SESSION['id_registro'] = $_POST['id_registro'];
            //$st['id_registro']=$_POST['id'];
            header('location:panelFuncionario.php');
        }
        else{
            $mensaje="no se pudo iniciar sesion";
        }
   }

}

}catch(PDOException $error){
$mensaje=$error->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Y la página donde me lleva si el `login` es correcto:

```
<?php
/*GENERA UNA NUEVA SESIÓN*/
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['rut_funcionario'])){

//echo "Bienvenido" .$_SESSION['rut_funcionario'];

    $id = $_POST['id_registro'];

//Boton de Cierre de Sesión
//echo '<a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesión </a>';

}
else{
header('location:ingresarIncidencia.php');
}
?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                <h3><?php echo "Bienvenido(a) has iniciado sesión con el RUT: " .$_SESSION['rut_funcionario']. "Identificador: " .$_SESSION['id_registro']; ?> 
   </h3>
                </div>
                   <div class="col-lg-4">
                   <?php echo '<a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cerrar 
            Sesión </a>'; ?>        
            </div>
            </div>
```

Agradezco a todos desde ya su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El posible error seria en que tu invocas o llamas a una variable sin datos

```
$_SESSION['id_registro'] = $_POST['id_registro'];
```

llamas al metodo post al id_registro, pero en el post solo tienes

- rut_funcionario
- password

lo que deberias hacer es acceder a la consulta que haces a la base de datos y obtener de esa consulta el id_registro no del post 
ejemplo:

```
// Creando conexion 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// verificando conexion
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexion Fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

**select:**

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

ahora mi consulta tendria en result en teoria debo acceder a result[0]['firstname'] o el dato que deseo !!
suerte !!

Comment: hola gracias por tu tiempo, trabajo con pdo, para hacer "result[o]['id_registro']" deberia ir dentro del array?  $consulta = "SELECT * from tbl_funcionario WHERE rut_funcionario = :rut_funcionario AND password = :password";
  $st = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
  $st->execute(
   array(

    'rut_funcionario' => $_POST['rut_funcionario'],
    'password' => $_POST['password']
    //'id_registro' => $_POST['id_registro']
   )
  );
  $contador = $st->rowCount();
   
   if ($contador > 0) {
    //ACA DEBERIA IR?
   }
   else{
    $mensaje="no se pudo iniciar sesion";
   }

Comment: en efecto ejemplo:  https://pastebin.com/P4pG322m

Answer (score 0):

En el arreglo estas asignando llaves a valores, seguramente aquí tienes el problema, ya que no tienes un valor para al cual le estas asignando la llave 'id_registro' (es decir, no estas utilizando los entregados por la consulta). Porque no utilizas la función `mysql_fetch_array` que te devolverá el arreglo resultante de la consulta y le asignas llaves para después poder utilizarlos valores.

```
$consulta = "SELECT * from tbl_funcionario WHERE rut_funcionario = :rut_funcionario AND password = :password";

... (conexion y eso)...

$row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta);
$result_data = array(
            'rut_funcionario' => row[0],
            'password' => row[1],
            'id_registro' => row[2]
);
```

y ya despues los envias.

Comment: hola estimado gracias por tu tiempo...al trabajar con pdo también puedo usar mysql_fetch_array? deberia entonces cambiar esta parte: $st = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
  $st->execute(
   array(

    'rut_funcionario' => $_POST['rut_funcionario'],
    'password' => $_POST['password']
    //'id_registro' => $_POST['id_registro']
   )
  );

Comment: Tienes razón intenta con el equivalente para PDO FETCH_ASSOC 
    $st = $conexion->prepare($consulta); 
    $st->execute();

    // Devolver un array indexado por nombre de colunmna
    $st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $row = $st->fetch(); Después obtendrías los valores con $row['nombre_campo_tabla']

Comment: creo que funciona, es posible pasar el valor de $row['nombre_campo_tabla'] a otra pagina? intento con $row['nombre_funcionario'] = $_POST['nombre_funcionario']; y en la pagina de destino tengo $id = $_POST[id_registro]; pero me da error Undefined index

Comment: Claro, pero intenta al reves $_POST['nombre_funcionario'] = $row['nombre_funcionario']

Comment: no me resulta jeje...lo defino como me comentas, y en la pagina de destino me sigue apareciendo error: undefined index

Comment: El nombre de la etiqueta del POST que mandas debetener el mismo en la otra pagina, es decir si envias $_POST['nombre_funcionario'] o $_POST['id_registro'], deberas recibirlo en la otra pagina como $nombre = $_POST['nombre_funcionario'] o $id = ['id_registro'] respectivamente.

Answer (score 0):

hola si entendi bien creo que el problema esta aca

```
$_SESSION['id_registro'] = $_POST['id_registro'];
```

tenes que tomar el id del usuario desde la base de datos primero y ahi seteas la sesion